# What kind of deflate compression is this?

Tags: decompress

I must be missing something obvious here. I cannot make sense of the following deflate stream.

Steps:

```
% wget https://github.com/lrq3000/mri_protocol/raw/master/SiemensVidaProtocol/Coma%20Science%20Group.exar1
% sqlite3 Coma\ Science\ Group.exar1 "SELECT writefile('ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c.raw', Data) FROM Content WHERE hash = 'ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c'"
% file ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c.raw
ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c.raw: data
```

However upon closer look:

```
% binwalk -X ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c.raw | head

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Raw deflate compression stream
```

Looking at the entropy (`binwalk -EJ`), this really looks like a typical deflate algorithm:

[image]

But it seems the signature is broken:

```
% zlib-flate -uncompress < ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c.raw
flate: inflate: data: incorrect header check
```

Anyone recognize the compression here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is indeed pure deflate bitstream. `zlib-flate` is for zlib stream.

```
% ./decomp.py ae126b7a3fe86811f981f53cf7cf59cfc1e5bc7c.raw | colrm 82
b'EDF V1: ContentType=syngo.MR.ExamDataFoundation.Data.EdfAddInConfigContent;\r\n
```

With simply:

```
% cat decomp.py
#!/bin/env python3
import zlib
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as input_file:
    compressed_data = input_file.read()
    unzipped = zlib.decompress(compressed_data, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    print(unzipped)
```

Ref:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310760/136285